# How to place a double circle below the center of two horizontal rectangles joined by labeled arrows to circle in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

What I have tried:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, quotes, arrows.meta, arrows, calc, shadows, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 10mm and -50mm,
circ/.style={draw, circle, ultra thick, double=pink!60, double distance = .5pt, text width=15mm, fill=white, draw=black, ultra thick, align=center},
rec/.style={draw, rectangle, fill=white, draw=black, ultra thick, minimum height = 1cm, minimum width=1cm, text width = 2cm, align=center},
every edge/.style = {draw, line width = 5mm, black, ultra thick, -Stealth},
]
\begin{scope}
\node (in)  [rec][left]{ABC};
\node (in0) [rec][left =of in]{DEF};                
\node (sa)  [circ] [below left=of in] {Generalized Ruleset};
\end{scope}
\draw[->] (in) edge (sa);
\draw[->] (in0) edge (sa);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I need to put two horizontal rectangles and a circle just below at the center of the two horizontal rectangles joined by arrows. I know it can be done, but at present I am unable to do it. Please help. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many options, here is a very basic one:

```
\path (in) -- (in0) node[midway,below=3em,circ] (sa)  {Gen-\\ eralized Ruleset};
```

Full minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
circ/.style={draw, circle, ultra thick, double=pink!60, double distance = .5pt, text width=15mm, fill=white, draw=black, ultra thick, align=center},
rec/.style={draw, rectangle, fill=white, draw=black, ultra thick, minimum height = 1cm, minimum width=1cm, text width = 2cm, align=center},
every edge/.style = {draw, line width = 5mm, black, ultra thick, -Stealth},
]
\begin{scope}
\node (in)  [rec][left]{ABC};
\node (in0) [rec][left =of in]{DEF};   
\path (in) -- (in0) node[midway,below=3em,circ] (sa)  {Gen-\\ eralized Ruleset};
\end{scope}
\draw[->] (in) edge (sa)  (in0) edge (sa);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also draw this as a tree with forest.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{circ/.style={draw, circle, ultra thick, double=pink!60, double distance = .5pt, text width=15mm, fill=white, draw=black, ultra thick, align=center},
rec/.style={draw, rectangle, fill=white, draw=black, ultra thick, minimum height = 1cm, minimum width=1cm, text width = 2cm, align=center},
my edge/.style = {draw, line width = 5mm, black, ultra thick, Stealth-},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow=north,edge=my edge,s sep+=2em,l sep+=2em}
[Gen-\\ eralized Ruleset,circ,
 [ABC,rec]
 [DEF,rec]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps me.